# https via cloudfront and S3 bucket of AWS doesn't work

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have done all the work by learning a tutorial in Youtube, so I was successful to make the domain name of Cloudfront distribution linking to my S3 bucket with only an index.html in it. (there is a little lock icon in the url).

Here is the problem, when I upload Angular dist folder into this same bucket, I can also get access the content; however, the little lock icon change to a circled exclamation icon, and shows that the website is not FULLY secure.

[image]
some helps me please

Comment: It could be that your angular app uses some api that is http, not https. Please check in your browses console for details of connections.

Comment: Thank you, when I open the console, is says:main.ddabf8aff5b12259da80.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dr2...778cr.cloudfront.net/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/neowebdeveloper'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.      so  I should change 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/neowebdeveloper' to 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/neowebdeveloper' ?

Comment: Everything must be `https`, otherwise you get Mixed Content errors/warnings.

Comment: Thanks, for saving my time, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by [Mixed Content](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/) connections caused by using **http** along with **https**.

To solve the problem, all http connections must be changed to https.